# Is there a way to count non-consecutive and consecutive candles or to solve my problem in TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

My stratedy is based on conditions:

From the last 4 candles, if:

3 out of 4 candles are with the trend, take the trade. BUT: if the last candle is against the trend, don't take the trade.

It sounds confusing but I attached the picture, so is stupid simple, however I have NO IDEA how to do this on pine, I am new at this and a little help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
ThreeValidInLastFour = ta.sum(condition ? 1 : 0, 4) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit update to Daveatt's answer, because you say you won't take the trade if the last candle is not in the trend:

`ThreeValidInLastFour = ta.sum(condition ? 1 : 0, 4) >= 3 and condition`